# try google webfonts on html5 canvas every method: standard, @import, javascript and webfont loader, neither work

Tags: html5-canvas, google-webfonts

I need render google web fonts on html5 canvas. I tried every method : standard, @import, javascript and webfont loader but they all fail. My html can be found at  https://gist.github.com/susquehanna/5851382 . Any idea? Thank you.

update:
works on jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/susquehanna/44k4U/3/

Comment: Did you check if the font is usable for ordinary HTML (some body text with this font applied)? Please make a fiddle (ie. jsfiddle.net) so it's possible to run some tests.

Comment: jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/susquehanna/44k4U/3/ . it works but after I write to html upload website it doesn't .